# make on ChicagoBoss failing with escript: exception error: undefined function rebar:main/1

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar3, chicagoboss

I am trying to install ChicagoBoss based on the instructions [here](http://chicagoboss.org/download.htm). Now, Make is failing with exception -

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Dec-2022::11:15:33.605319 ===
beam/beam_load.c(148): Error loading module rebar:
  please re-compile this module with an Erlang/OTP 25 compiler


escript: exception error: undefined function rebar:main/1
  in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 750)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
  in call from init:start_em/1 
  in call from init:do_boot/3 
make: *** [compile] Error 127
```

I have further installed rebar3 using command -

```
homebrew install rebar3
```

I am running Erlang OTP/25 in mac. I haven't been able to understand if it's a problem with

```
rebar3
```

or

```
ChicagoBoss
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with ChicagoBoss. It includes a `rebar` binary that was compiled with Erlang/OTP release 17, but Erlang/OTP release 25 can only use modules compiled with release 21 or later.

The `rebar` binary starts with the line `#!/usr/bin/env escript`, meaning that it looks for `escript` in the `PATH`. This picks up release 25, causing this problem. You could try installing release 24 or earlier to work around this.

You might find ASDF useful for switching between Erlang versions: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang